# In Handsontable How do you save records with specific ids each row?

Tags: handsontable

I have this set of records object-array like for example..

`[{firstname:'John',lastname:'Smith'},{firstname:'Jimmy',lastname:'Morre'}]`

What I want to do is to enable Saving feature of Handsontable. My problem is I can't update it where column name is "firstname" or "lastname" .. or at least row id (where can I put rowID by the way?) because the getData() function returns only values of the cell not the with the properties of the original data-set such as like 'firstname ' and 'lastname'.

Anyone from here who are more familiar with Handsontable? thank you..

Comment: Once you did a `getData()`, what prevent you to construct your resulting object-array as you need with the help of `getRowHeader()` and/or `getColHeader()` ? (Note that getRowHeader will only work if you defined it, 'rowHeaders: true' by default). Can you tell what is the resulting object-array you would like to have after pushing the save button ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand what you want.

But in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/am5dmmbt/) you can see how to get the property of your data ;)

```
var datas = hot.getData()

$.each(datas, function(rowIndex, row) {
  console.log('The row id is ' + rowIndex);

  $.each(row, function(colIndex, value) {
    console.log('The column id is ' + colIndex + ' and the property is ' + Object.keys(hot.getSchema())[colIndex]);
    console.log(value);
  });

  console.log("----------------------------");
});
```

I hope it helps you.